# How to sort data Sequelize belongsToMany associations?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to sort results for below schema using Sequelize. But I am getting an error like `Unable to find a valid association for the model, 'UserProject'`

Please find my code below, Actually, I want to sort the results by `UserProject.role`

```
UserProject = sequelize.define('user_project', { role: Sequelize.STRING});
User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: UserProject });
User.findAll({
    include: {
      required: true,
      through: {
        attributes: [],
        model: UserProject
      },
      model:Project,
      order: [[{ model: UserProject}, "role", "ASC"]]
});
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

what about try this?

```
User.findAll({
    include: {
      required: true,
      through: {
        attributes: [],
        model: UserProject
      },
      model:Project
    },
    order: [[UserProject, "role", "ASC"]]
});
```

Comment: I am getting Same Error